# error in adding the first column as the row name in r

Tags: r, row, rename

I'm trying to name my row names by the first column in R. But error `invalid 'row.names' length` present.

df

```
   x1   A   B
1  a    2   1
2  b    4   2
```

expected output

```
     A    B
a    2    1
b    4    2
```

my code

```
df1 <- df[, -1] #remove the first column x1 and create a new df->df1
rownames(df1) <- df[, 1] #add the row names by the first column of df
```

Error

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't reproduce the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: Anyway, you can try `df %>% set_rownames(.$x1) %>% select(-x1)` using magrittr package

Comment: @agenis weird, it shows in my R. It writes `Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.` in addition, is it meaningful to you? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Kay - I was able to reproduce your error. The answer can be found below.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the first answer, I can suggest also:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% data.frame %>% set_rownames(.$x1) %>% select(-x1)
```

or

```
library(tibble)
data.frame(column_to_rownames(df, var = "x1"))
```

Eventually, to understand why your initial data.frame gave an error in setting the row.names, its because of the subsetting. You'll see this is not really a vector:

```
    dim(df[, 1]) 
#### [1] 2 1
```

It's due to particularities of the tibble format of your initial data.frame.
Thanks to @thelatemail for the help.